# How to make hibernation work on a Dell XPS 9365

Tags: hibernate, xps

I use an XPS 9365, running Vanilla GNOME Shell on Ubuntu 17.10.

At the beginning, hibernation command "sudo pm-hibernate" didn't work at all.
Then, doing my research, I understood the only way to put your computer in hibernation was to put Ubuntu in Airplane mode (shutting off Wifi and Bluetooth).
So now 'sudo pm-hibernate' command works (flashing the session state on the SSD, than powering off the laptop).
But when I power on my laptop again, it reloads a new fresh new session with bluetooth activated.

I read also about bcrm driver or something.

Would there be a way to make hibernation a success ?
Thanks a lot for your reading ;)

Yoann

Comment: Hibernation in Linux is not very well supported and very buggy; that's why it's disabled by default.